# Parallel.For takes longer than for loop

Tags: for-loop, omnithreadlibrary

In Delphi Berlin 10.1, I have a `for` loop:

```
for i := 0 to slSMP.Count - 1 do
begin
  if System.StrUtils.Containstext(slSMP.ValueFromIndex[i], ThisSearchTerm) or
    System.StrUtils.Containstext(ExtractFileName(ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(slSMP.Names[i])), ThisSearchTerm) then
  begin
    slTempSearchList.Add(slSMP.Names[i] + slSMP.ValueFromIndex[i]);
  end;
end;
```

*slSMP* and *slTempSearchList* obviously are of type `TStringList`.

Unfortunately, this loop takes too much time, so I decided to transform it into a `OtlParallel.Parallel.For` loop:

```
OtlParallel.Parallel.For(0, slSMP.Count - 1).Execute(
  procedure (i: integer)
  begin
    if System.StrUtils.Containstext(slSMP.ValueFromIndex[i], ThisSearchTerm) or
      System.StrUtils.Containstext(ExtractFileName(ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(slSMP.Names[i])), ThisSearchTerm) then
    begin
      slTempSearchList.Add(slSMP.Names[i] + slSMP.ValueFromIndex[i]);
      //CodeSite.Send('TformSearchStartMenu.DoSearchFromSearchEdit: i', i);
    end;
  end);
```

STRANGELY, when the `CodeSite.Send` line is DEACTIVATED, this loop never finishes, so I had to close the application with the task manager.

But when the `CodeSite.Send` line is ACTIVATED, the loop finishes, but it takes LONGER than the simple `for` loop.

So how can I make this loop faster with parallel programming?
 
And why does the `OtlParallel.Parallel.For` only work when the `CodeSite.Send` line is ACTIVATED? How can I make it work without the `CodeSite.Send` line?

Comment: Code looks fine and the program should not hang. It is impossible to say why without a reproducible test case. And, of course it works slower if you send information to CodeSite in each loop.

Comment: Might be slower because it takes time to set up the background threads. SO making it work parallel would only benefit for large lists. Moreover I worry about the slTempSearchList, if it is shared between threads you'll run into serious race condition problems.